# Google Colabにperfライブラリのインストールができない

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, pip

オライリー社の"実践　時系列解析"という本で学習を進めています。
この本のgithubリンクです -> https://github.com/PracticalTimeSeriesAnalysis/BookRepo

一番下に添付したコードの通り、この本ではエポックごとに更新される重みと結果を記録する管理システムとしてperfライブラリの `perf.write_val()` を用いているのですが、perfライブラリのインストールがうまくいきません。

まず、そのまま`import perf`を実行すると、`no module named`となるので

```
!pip install perf
```

とgoogle colab上で実行するのですが、その際

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement perf (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for perf
```

と表示されてしまい、インストールがうまく進みません。

pipのバージョンによるインストールの失敗かと考え、

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

と実行し最新のバージョンで再度試しましたが、うまくいきませんでした。

・実際に実行しようとしたコード
https://github.com/PracticalTimeSeriesAnalysis/BookRepo/blob/master/Ch10/ForecastingElectricity.ipynb

```
################
## TRAINING ##
################

def train(symbol, iter_train, valid_iter, iter_test,
          data_names, label_names,
          save_dir, gpu):
    ## save training information/results 
    if not os.path.exists(SAVE_DIR):
        os.makedirs(SAVE_DIR)
    printFile = open(os.path.join(SAVE_DIR, 'log.txt'), 'w')
    def print_to_file(msg):
        print(msg)
        print(msg, file = printFile, flush = True)
    ## print_to_file(args) ## preserve configuation to enable hyperparameter optimization
    ## archiving results header
    print_to_file('Epoch     Training Cor     Validation Cor')


    ## storing prior epoch's values to set an improvement threshold
    ## terminates early if progress slow
    buf     = RingBuffer(THRESHOLD_EPOCHS)
    old_val = None

    ## mxnet boilerplate
    ## defaults to 1 gpu of which index is 0
    ##devs = [mx.gpu(gpu)]
    devs   = mx.cpu()
    module = mx.mod.Module(symbol,
                           data_names=data_names,
                           label_names=label_names,
                           context=devs)
    module.bind(data_shapes=iter_train.provide_data,
                label_shapes=iter_train.provide_label)
    module.init_params(mx.initializer.Uniform(0.1))
    module.init_optimizer(optimizer='adam',
                          optimizer_params={'learning_rate': LR})

    ## training
    for epoch in range( N_EPOCHS):
        iter_train.reset()
        iter_val.reset()
        for batch in iter_train:
            module.forward(batch, is_train=True) # compute predictions
            module.backward()                    # compute gradients
            module.update()                      # update parameters

        ## training results
        train_pred  = module.predict(iter_train).asnumpy()
        train_label = iter_train.label[0][1].asnumpy()
        train_perf  = perf.write_eval(train_pred, train_label,
                                      save_dir, 'train', epoch)

        ## validation results
        val_pred  = module.predict(iter_val).asnumpy()
        val_label = iter_val.label[0][1].asnumpy()
        val_perf = perf.write_eval(val_pred, val_label,
                                   save_dir, 'valid', epoch)

        print_to_file('%d         %f       %f ' % (epoch, train_perf['COR'], val_perf['COR']))
        
        if epoch > 0:                                # if we don't yet have measures of improvement, skip
            buf.append(val_perf['COR'] - old_val) 
        if epoch > 2:                                # if we do have measures of improvement, check them
            vals = buf.get()
            # print(vals)
            # print(COR_THRESHOLD)
            vals = [v for v in vals if v != 0]
            if sum([v < COR_THRESHOLD for v in vals]) == len(vals):
                print_to_file('EARLY EXIT')
                break
        old_val = val_perf['COR']
                
    ## testing
    test_pred  = module.predict(iter_test).asnumpy()
    test_label = iter_test.label[0][1].asnumpy()
    test_perf = perf.write_eval(test_pred, test_label, save_dir, 'tst', epoch)
    print_to_file('\n TESTING PERFORMANCE')
    print_to_file(test_perf)
```

Comment: [PyPIでの検索結果](https://pypi.org/search/?q=perf)や[Anaconda.orgでの検索結果](https://anaconda.org/search?q=perf)にはそういうモジュールは無さそうです。正確にはAnaconda.orgにはperfはあるのですが、インストール後にimportするのはpyperfという別の名前です。参照ソースコード最終更新からの2年の間にperfが終了・削除されたか名前が変わったのかもしれません。あるいは書籍のどこかに記述されているローカルなモジュールなのかも？ GitHubのリポジトリにIssueを出して聞いてみるのが早いと思われます。

Comment: 出版社に質問はされましたか？以前オライリーの別の書籍でデータのダウンロードが出来なかった際には、対応策を教えてもらいました。（回答まで数日～1週間程度は待ちましょう）